# How to set an object which is at rest to uniform velocity motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider I place an object in space where there are no frictional forces.
Now according to Newtons first law, it stays at rest, until acted upon by an unbalanced force.

Now how to make this object attain uniform velocity?

Comment: Why do you think a force would lead to uniform velocity motion?

Comment: Newton's law says $F\propto a$, so why would you *ask* if an applied force would lead to uniform velocity motion?

Comment: @KyleKanos My main query is "how do you make an object which is at rest ... acquire uniform velocity"? .... The answer given below makes sense ... but still i am not convinced! ...

Comment: Then you should modify your post to ask that question, because you currently have [a few close votes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/113026) for "unclear what you're asking."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are applying the force, the object will move accelerated. At the moment when you stop applying the force, the object will keep moving uniform with its current velocity.

By Newtons 2nd Law: $F=\frac{dp}{dt} \Rightarrow dp=Fdt$, where dp is the change of momentum. Momentum, by definion, equals mass times velocity ($p=mv$). So as long as you have force, you will have the changing of momentum, and if the mass is constant, the change of velocity.

Comment: thanks for the answer! ... If we know the value of Force applied F, mass of the object m, and t be the time for which force is applied, then is this calculation correct which finds final uniform velocity? => a = F/m, vfinal = vinitial(which is 0) + at